# Change heap size for Eclipse installed as a snap package

Tags: eclipse, heap-memory, snapcraft

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.1 and have Eclipse installed as a snap package. I want to change the values of `Xms` and `Xmx`, but I can't edit `/snap/eclipse/29/eclipse.ini` because it is read-only. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Do you actually want to change the values in the eclipse.ini which change the settings for Eclipse itself - or do you want to change the settings for Java programs you are running (which are elsewhere)?

Comment: Might be able to write a shell script that launches it and then pass the the values to the executable - not sure if they'd get over written though my whats in the eclipse.ini

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I want to change the settings for Eclipse itself.

Comment: This should be possible via an override: https://github.com/snapcrafters/eclipse/pull/41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the arguments if you run eclipse via the command-line:

```
snap run eclipse -vmargs -Xmx15g
```